# Why the address is 0xF000:0xE05B in the long jump instruction located at 0xFFFF0 in BIOS?

Tags: assembly, x86, bios, real-mode

We know that on x86 when power is on, CS register is set to 0xF000 and IP is set to 0xFFF0. And the instruction at 0xFFFF0 is `jmp far 0xF000:0xE05B`. The question is why is it `0xE05B` but not other addresses? If it is for compatibility, how does its BIOS designer think? Is there any special reason or just pick a random address?

Answer (score 1):

The physical address 0xFFFF0 (0xF000:0xFFF0) is part of the BIOS address space. The address that gets jumped to from there is BIOS dependent so may not always be `jmp far 0xF000:0xE05B`. The address you show is typical for some of the virtual BIOSes, but doesn't have to be that specific address.